# Register stylesheet for message header

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, thunderbird-addon, xbl

I'm trying extend xbl for `mail-tagfield` tag. This tag is being used during message display.

My extension is bootstrap and it uses window opened observer to apply any css to that window. using this code:

```
var sss = Cc["@mozilla.org/content/style-sheet-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIStyleSheetService),
    css = ios.newURI("chrome://myextension/skin/myStyle.css", null, null);

if (!sss.sheetRegistered(css, sss.USER_SHEET))
    sss.loadAndRegisterSheet(css, sss.USER_SHEET);
```

Evidently such css is only applied to chrome itself and not to tabmail, which what I actually needed:

[image]

What would be a best approach to register a stylesheet in tabmail?

Answer (score 0):

Well, turned out the solution was as simple as adding **!important** to the binding in css file...

My assumption about stylesheet not being register for tabmail was incorrect.